# RegExp match with string at the end

Tags: javascript

I have the following sample URL that I would like my RegExp to match with the &page=2 string at the end, how can I achieve this?

abc.com/sub/?atm=qwerty2&page=2

The code that I currently have:

```
var test = new RegExp("(abc.com)"+holder+"[?](atm)[=][a-zA-Z0-9!@#%=+<>^$&*();:,\".?\'/]");
```

What I've tried:

```
var test = new RegExp("(abc.com)"+holder+"[?](atm)[=][a-zA-Z0-9!@#%=+<>^$&*();:,\".?\'/]"+"&page=[0-9]$");
```

Answer (score 2):

simple use this pattern `&\w+=\d+$`

1. `$` target with end of the string
2. pattern is the `&string=num`

   [**Demo Regex**](https://regex101.com/r/xbsrrH/2/)

```js
var a="abc.com/sub/?atm=qwerty2&page=2";
console.log(a.match(/&\w+=\d+$/g)[0])
```

Comment: Would this work?

var test = new RegExp("(abc.com)"+sub+"[?](atm)[=][a-zA-Z0-9!@#%=+<>^$&*();:,\".?\'/].match(/&\w+=\d+$)");

Comment: I created alternate regex pattern for find the `&page=2` end of the string .Its match you need .Then why use this *`var test = new RegExp("(abc.com)"+sub+"[?](atm)[=][a-zA-Z0-9!@#%=+<>^$&*();‌​:,\".?\'/].match(/&\‌​w+=\d+$)");`* .What is the use of it?